# Jquery how to select dynamically created radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery how to select dynamically created radio button. I have

```
<div id="rDataR">
</div>
```

MY JAVASCRIPT

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
    var items="<p>";

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

      items+="<input type='radio' id='myrdb' value='"+i+"'/>"

    }
    items+="</p>"
    $("#rDataR").html(items);

    }
    </script>
```

I try this, but not working

```
$('#myrdb').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                alert($(this).val());
            }
        });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: There are many errors in your code. Not closed the function properly, not defined the length, etc.

Comment: i forgot to close the function.

Comment: You're defining multiple elements with the same id. Don't do that. The id is supposed to be unique in a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like following:

```
$(document).on('click','#myrdb',function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert($(this).val());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using duplicate id use class for user inputs
then access them:

```
$(function(){
 $('.myrdb').filter(':checked').click(function(){alert('I am checked')})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the dynamically added html to

```
items+="<input type='radio' class='myrdb' value='"+i+"'/>"
```

Since as per the convention `dom id's` must be unique.

And the jQuery event handler be like:

```
$(document).on('click','.myrdb',function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     alert($(this).val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You logic is correct. You just missed some terminal colons here and there and had one small stray typo and you haven't defined your length.
I also changed your radio elements to use class instead of id so they can be uniquely identified  consistently.
The changes are now as follows:

**Your HTML:**
`<div id="rDataR"></div>`

**Your JavaScript**
`<script>
    $(function() {
        var items = "<p>";
        var length = 10; //added length
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            items += "<input type='radio' class='myrdb' value='" + i + "'/>";
        }
        items += "</p>";
        $("#rDataR").html(items); //corrected the typo #rDataE 
    });
</script>`

**Your Trigger**
`$(".myrdb").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});`

Let me know how it goes